# Monitoring Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

So the problem is I have a `ThreadManager` class which use queue to hold the `Task` objects; the `ThreadManager` can start the `Task` by invoking the `Task`'s `Start()` method from which will generate a thread to run some algorithm (the actual "task"). Now what I want to achieve is to let the `ThreadManager` to monitor the status of the task thread (generated from the `Start()` method of the `Task` object).

For this to work, I think I need to create a thread to do the monitoring in the `ThreadManager`, and I need a way to let the task thread to fire events to notify the monitor thread that I am finished or I encountered some error, so the monitor can handle these event accordingly.

Gurus, please advise me if my idea is applicable? And if it is, how to achieve this workflow? Many thanks!

Comment: Running a `Task` won't usually create a new thread, it will reuse one of the threadpool threads.

Comment: Task.factory.startnew does :)

Comment: No, it does not. It really uses one of the threadpool threads.

Comment: @zenwalker, no it doesn't - Task.Factory.StartNew creates a new Task and starts the Task.  It is the same thing as creating a task using the constructor and calling Start to schedule it for work.

Comment: @baboon: Is this about `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or something you wrote yourself?

Comment: @Matt, 
well sorry mate, my bad. Thats what i meant actually. Damn :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `Task.ContinueWith` to schedule a continuation for each of the tasks and then change the status depending on the result of the task in your continuation.  You know that the task has been started (because you called `Start()`) - you just need to know when the task completes.  If it fails, is cancelled, or finishes, you can observe that in the continuation task and then you can update your status.  The continuation task is an `Action<Task>`, which receives the completed task.  You can call `task.Status` to get the status of that completed task.

Then you don't need to have a separate thread/task to monitor the status periodically.

Comment: OK, then how does your task work?  Does it expose its status or have some way of notifying other threads when it's done?  Can you have your custom tasks "do something extra" when they're finished so you can do the bookkeeping?

Comment: when it gets the work done, or raise an exception in the task, it will set some parameter in the object, I want to notify the monitoring thread, but I don't know how set up all this..(fire an event, but I want the monitoring thread to handle this event)

Comment: Ok, but the disadvantage to that approach is that you have to have a separate monitoring thread, and it will have to regularly poll all of the tasks, which is a lot of unnecessary work.  Why can't you use an existing Task library like TPL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Task.IsCompleted property on each of the Task objects you may have in your manager collection. Hope this is what your asking?