# Task with event notification - .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Yesterday on SO, i saw a thread asking for a code which some what does this way. I mean, you (manager thread) start number of tasks using TPL APIs and once they are completed job, that thread should notify you (Manager) back who maintains Task pool.

So here is the code which i tried. Although i must say it works as i describe above.

```
class TaskJob
{
    public delegate void NotificationDelegate(int? taskId,string message);
    public event NotificationDelegate NotifyCompletion;

    public void TaskToRun()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Task.CurrentId == 4)//If its a 4th thread, simulate exception
                throw new Exception();

            Console.WriteLine("Task started with thread id " + Task.CurrentId);
            Thread.Sleep(100000);

            Console.WriteLine("Task finished with thread id " + Task.CurrentId);

            NotifyCompletion(Task.CurrentId, "Successfully completed");
        }
        catch
        {
            NotifyCompletion(Task.CurrentId, "Faulted error");
        }
    }        
}

class Program
{
    static List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//starting 5 threads/tasks
        {
            TaskJob tb = new TaskJob();
            tb.NotifyCompletion += new ConsoleApplication1.TaskJob.NotificationDelegate(tb_NotifyCompletion);
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(tb.TaskToRun);
            taskList.Add(t);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        CheckAndDispose();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void CheckAndDispose()
    {
        foreach (var item in taskList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status of task = " + item.Id + " is = " + item.Status);
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }

    static void tb_NotifyCompletion(int? taskId, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task with id completed ="+ taskId + " with message = " + message);            
    }
}
```

Couple of heads up:

1. Dont worry about not maintaining Task[] rather than having a list and then converting to array. Its just a code. Not that i am concentrating on efficiency.
2. Am not worried on custom Dispose implementation as of now.

Now i am asking myself couple of questions, but fail to convince myself with an suitable answer. Here are they:

1. Is this way solving the problem good? Or is there a better way to do it? Code please :)
2. How to make sure that the tasks objects are really disposed (upon calling Dispose) but not implementing the custom Dispose pattern.
3. Have not done any memory leak test using tools. But just visual sake, do you see leaks?
4. In the for loop (main method) i am creating TaskJob class objects which are local to loop. Thus these objects gets gc'd (lets say out of scope) after loop completion. So, how the event is fired back which i am hooking up using this object but it has been disposed after loop when actually the event is fired.
5. Any thing else you wish to add?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7293871/60761) yesterday wasn't about TPL tasks.

Comment: huh what? the OP tasks about Tasks and the solution is talking about what jon answered. So its on TPL.

Comment: And kind reason for downvote please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no need to do this yourself at all - use continuations with [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663.aspx) or [`Task<T>.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321274.aspx). That basically lets you say what to do when a task completes - including executing different code on failure, cancellation, and success.

It also *returns* a task, so you can then continue when that's completed etc.

Oh, and you can give it a `TaskScheduler`, so that from a UI thread you can say, "When this background task finishes, execute the given delegate on the UI thread" or similar things.

This is the approach that C# 5 async methods are built on.

Comment: Ok can my code be a simualation of ContinueWith feature in TPL? i mean if there werent there.

Comment: @zenwalker - why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Not exactly re-inventing, rather brainstorming self or being curious :)

Comment: @zenwalking: Well reinventing the same idea - I think it would definitely be a better idea to just use the existing mechanism directly rather than wrapping it in your own.

Comment: @Adam It never was a real problem to start with.

Comment: Okies, but still it wud be of great help if any body could answer those questions of mine. i am being damn curious tho re-inventing or what ever. I am just curious myself being lame :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: You said above "...you can give it a TaskScheduler, so that from a UI thread you can say, "When this background task finishes, execute the given delegate on the UI thread" or similar things." => I have assigned my own TaskScheduler, but I do not see any event or something to notify me about "a task has finished". Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @jreichert: You can use `ContinueWith` (as per the answer) with the delegate to execute when the target task has finished. Specify the scheduler in the `ContinueWith` call.

Comment: Thanks for the `ContinueWith` reminder. I was just trying to figure out how to get a service to call a `Stop` function when a task is cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can try using async / await pattern. If you await a Task that means the compiler will automatically generate the ContinueWith for you.

If you use this pattern you can write normal async methods which will itself generate State machine.

Check my post

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/async.aspx

Rx on the other hand can represent your data flow, I mean you can hook a sequence of jobs and subscribe your observable on an Observer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Comment: Well thanks for the alternative solution. But assuming on this solution, other qs can be answered? thanks