# How to run a collection of tasks, pause them all, update a datatable and then allow the tasks to continue with the updated datatable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I have 4 tasks, each running the same method but with different parameters. Each task is reading data from a datatable.

**EDIT:** The data i need the analyse is too large to load it all into memory. Im therefore going to use paging to retrieve smaller block of the data. The process would therefore be as follows:

1. Create X number of tasks, with a for loop/task.Factory, and manually assign the parameters to each task. (Ive already looked into the parallel for loop.)
2. Wait until all the tasks have finished running through the 1st page of data.
3. Load the 2nd page of data into the data table.
4. The same X tasks would **RECOMMENCE** running through the new data
5. Repeat until all the data has been read from the database.

**END EDIT**

I need a way of waiting for each task to have finished reading all the data in the datatable before i go to sql server and retrieve the next page of data.

At present i was thinking of doing the following:
Declare 2 variables inside the object (myEntity) i pass into the method,

1 = number of tasks created (myEntity.TaskCount).

2 = a counter for how many tasks have finished (myEntity.Count).

```
public List<int> GetData(object myEntity)
{
    List<int> myList;

    if(rowCounter == myDataTable.Rows.Count)
    {
        myEntity.Count++;

        while(myEntity.Count != myEntity.TaskCount)
        {

        }
         
        //Refill datatable with new data.
        //rowCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        myList = new List<int>();
        
        //Assign the values to each tasks myList.   
    }
    return myList;
}
```

[Question 1] How can i pause the tasks, update the datatable and then allow them to continue?

[Question 2] myList is task specific (ie i would have 4 different myList's since i have 4 tasks) or would its value be shared among all the tasks?

Comment: The tasks are created in a for loop and the work load is manually distributed between them. I had a look into the Parallel For loop but the work load is very similar so im just using a for loop to create the tasks. I havent written the code yet, im just at the stage of trying to figure out how i should structure things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContinueWith` method from TPL for waiting all child tasks.
Something like this:

```
var parentTask = new Task(() => {
    new Task(() => YourFunction1(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
    new Task(() => YourFunction2(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
    new Task(() => YourFunction3(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
    new Task(() => YourFunction4(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
});

parentTask.ContinueWith(p => UpdateYourDatabase());

parentTask.Start(); //Start parent that will start its child tasks.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Alexander. From what i can understand, the above isnt what im looking for (my bad). Ill edit the original question and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` to wait on an array of tasks.

Simply add each of your generated tasks to a list and then wait on them before moving to the next page.

```
bool moreData = true;
while(moreData){
    // Go get the next page of data ...
    moreData = TryGetNextPage();

    // spin up the tasks
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Tasks>();
    for(int i = 0; i < maxLoops ; i++){
       Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { // your action } );
       tasks.Add(t);
     }

     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
 }
```

Comment: Hi Mike, cheers for the code. Unfortunately its still not what im looking for as i cant recommence the same tasks from where they were at the end of the first call.

Comment: Why do you need to stay on the same tasks?  Sounds like you need some sort of semaphore that the threads wait on when they're done but also signal the main thread so it can track when to release the semaphore.  This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297576/task-with-event-notification-net-4 has some code that might help if you absolutely must keep the threads around.